# method gives error to make method return void

Tags: java, android

```
public Step createStep(int position) {
    try {
        final StepFragmentSample step = new StepFragmentSample();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position);
        step.setArguments(b);
        return step;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test", "/Excp due to" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

It shows error:

> make method CreateStep return statement **void**

Why?

Comment: you need to use void or return something once the method gets executed.

Comment: but I return step then why its giving error?

Comment: return should be called after catch statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return something if an exception occurs:

```
public Step createStep(int position) {
    try {
        final StepFragmentSample step = new StepFragmentSample();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position);
        step.setArguments(b);
        return step;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test", "/Excp due to" + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

or

```
public Step createStep(int position) {
    try {
        final StepFragmentSample step = new StepFragmentSample();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position);
        step.setArguments(b);
        return step;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test", "/Excp due to" + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you sir@Jens

Comment: @sagar You are welcome

Comment: Sir, can I contact you other than here.mail or anything?@Jens

Answer (score 0):

You have to always return Step object. If there is going to be an exception in your code you will never return Step object.

Try something like this:

```
public Step createStep(int position) {
    try {
        final StepFragmentSample step = new StepFragmentSample();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position);
        step.setArguments(b);
        return step;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test", "/Excp due to" + e.toString());
    }
    return new Step(); // or return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
public Step createStep(int position) {
try {
    final StepFragmentSample step = new StepFragmentSample();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position);
    step.setArguments(b);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("/Test", "/Excp due to" + e.toString());
}
 return step;
}
```